# How to determine if Azure SQL Database has been inactive

Tags: sql-server, azure, telemetry

What is the best indication that Azure SQL Database has been inactive?

I am looking at the result of CPU Percentage, Data IO, and Success Connections/Failed Connections
If all values are 0 in a certain date range, is it safe to assume that Azure SQL Database has been inactive?

Marko

Answer (score 1):

Should work, but you should also check sys.event_log and sys.database_connection_stats to make sure. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-connection-stats-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current